# How to set up listener to salesforce outbound message in java using maven?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am trying to set up salesforce outbound messaging listener in java. This is the link I followed to set up, and it works fine - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_Eclipse_3.2

The article was unfortunately never updated after 2012, and I want to set this up as a maven project for obvious reasons -this is where I run into difficulties.

I am looking for the right maven plugin to basically reproduce whatever was in the link.The idea is that, I need to have an endpoint listener, such that it can receive a soap message from salesforce. With me right now, I have a wsdl file (that I get from salesforce), and this is my starting point. The endpoint is also included in the wsdl.
From a lot of research, I decided to use the apache cxf maven plugin to generate the classes from wsdl.
I also have a public endpoint available to receive the message.

However I am stuck and unsure as to how to to proceed from here. Once I get the classes, how do I configure the endpoint listener? 
From the  generated classes, there is one interface `NotificationPort` , which has the method that is called when a message hits the endpoint. I know that I need to have a class that implements the interface. How do I run and test the service from now?

This is my pom.xml

```
        <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cxf.version>3.1.11</cxf.version>
        <wsdl.generated.sources>${basedir}/src/main/java</wsdl.generated.sources>
    <wsdl.location>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/supplyorder.wsdl</wsdl.location>
    </properties>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${wsdl.generated.sources}</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${wsdl.location}</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

wsdl relevant parts

```
<!-- Binding 
     You need to write a service that implements this binding to receive the notifications
 -->
<binding name="NotificationBinding" type="tns:NotificationPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <operation name="notifications">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output> 
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<!-- Service Endpoint -->
<service name="NotificationService">
    <documentation>Notification Service Implementation</documentation>
    <port binding="tns:NotificationBinding" name="Notification">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/SupplyOrder/Notification"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Questions:
1. I wrote a custom class that implements the interface `NotificationsPort`. How do I run and test this web service? What can I use as run time environment to run it? Would tomcat work?

2. Is there anyway I can use Spring to get this set up? -as I would highly prefer to use that.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, I finally found a tutorial to have this set up. Follow this as is, and you're good to go. 
https://www.codenotfound.com/apache-cxf-spring-boot-soap-web-service-client-server-example.html